# What happened to this question's text?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

This question's text is rather... unusual. It was edited to normalize it, so here's the old version: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/c6503a4f-33b6-4825-a8f1-45f383d69065/view-source

On my work machine, with Google Chrome, the text is displayed like this:

[image]

I'm not sure what happened; anyways, is there a way to prevent this from happening in the future? It's rather harmless (I think), but certainly not desirable, either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are [CJK fullwidth forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms). The relevant context is terminals that can display almost fixed-width characters, with alphabetic symbols such as Latin letters taking one column and Chinese ideograms taking two columns. Fullwidth forms of Latin letters take two columns.

There is no display bug here. The post was made with these characters. There's no point in using these characters when the intent isn't to display them on a fixed-width terminal; the poster probably inadvertently pressed a key combination that changed the input mode in his browser.

Answer (score 5):

There is no formatting issue. Everything gets displayed as it should. The OP just posted some weird Unicode characters instead of normal letters.

For example, the character codes of `ｐｕｔ` are `65360`, `65365` and `65364`, respectively.